# Strange behavior for connection factory pool-size config in Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, activemq-classic, message-driven-bean

I'm quite new in j2ee world and I've got a configuration problem with my MDBs.
We're using Glassfish 3.1.2 and ActiveMQ 5.6.0 for our JMS queues (not topic, just queue).
We have deployed into Glassfish an Enterprise application containing 3 MDBs connected to 3 different JMS queues.

Each queue has the following configuration (from Glassfish admin console):

- intial-pool-size: 20
- max-pool-size: 64
- resize-quantity: 1

also we added the same configuration into the sun-ejb.xml file into the METADATA project folder.

To check its behavior, each MDB has got:

1. a static int variable (counter)
2. a private (non-static) int variable (internalCounter)
3. a constructor where we increment the static counter, assign its value to internalCounter and display the value into a log. In this way we give a "custom" unique ID to each MDB instance
4. a "onMessage" method with just a System.out.println(internalCounter) and a Thread.sleep(2000) (it's just for performance tests)

When we test the system with a big amount of messages (20-30 msg per second) we have noticed that our MDBs aren't able to process messages at the same speed we put them into the queues, so from the ActiveMQ web interface we see an increment of "enqueued messages" for each queue.

Checking the log, I found that:

1. Glassfish creates 30 MDB instances for each queue
2. Glassfish uses always the same 10 instances (instance #21 up to #30) for each queue while my expectation is to that Glassfish uses all of 30 MDB for each queue

I ran again this test with the following configuration (by admin-console and by the xml project file):

- intial-pool-size: 0
- max-pool-size: 64
- resize-quantity: 1

And in the log I found that Glassfish creates and uses only and again 10 MDB instances (#1 up to #10)

Please, could you help me ?

Thanks in advance and excuse me for my bad english

Alessio